# Multiple FastAPI services on the same page

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, kubernetes-ingress, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to create multiple services.

It works in a somewhat strange way, but basically I have a generic FastAPI service and a CI/CD that downloads multiple installable packages to create different services from it. It's all packaged neatly, I create multiple Docker images, then they are served by Kubernetes using deployments, services (separate pods, one container per pod) and ingress.

Now, I've configured ingress to serve those services from the same host. The only thing that is different for those services is the app root path. So for example I have:

- `foo.example.com/foo` - 1st service
- `foo.example.com/bar` - 2nd service

If I go to `foo.example.com/foo/docs`, I am greeted with Swagger documentation and I can select the app root path at the top of the page. Unfortunately, there's only one option: `/foo`. Same for the second service, but this time it's `/bar`.

Now I know that those services run in separate containers in separate pods in my k8s cluster, but I was wondering if there's a way to for example go to `foo.example.com` or to a particular service like `foo.example.com/foo` and have all the services listed in Swagger's drop-down menu, so I can select any of them and be redirected to it. It would be huge improvement from a user experience point of view.

@Edit, Ingress manifest file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    external-dns/manage-entries: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: foo-service
            port:
              number: 80
    host: test.example.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /bar/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: bar-service
            port:
              number: 80
    host: test.example.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /baz/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: baz-service
            port:
              number: 80
    host: test.example.com
```

Comment: Could you provide your yaml files to reproduce your situation? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: So k8s version is `1.19.12`. Everything runs on AWS. I do not have full access to cluster, I can only send in some k8s manifest files and that's it. I am afraid I cannot really share the manifests, but this is as simple as can be: a Service+Deployment for each service and then ingress that configures. I've added the ingress configuration to my question, the deployments are creating single-containers pods.

Comment: I know what dropdown you are talking about. I am also wondering about its purpose. I guess its nothing you can control from outside fastapi. You need to configure something in your applications.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is, the apps (fastapi services) don't know about each other. But if this is the only way to do it, I'll try to do this in FastAPI

Comment: You are using deprecated version of Kubernetes. Could you update it?

Comment: Nope, this is beyond my scope. We recently updated from `1.18.X` so I guess it's not gonna happen any time soon